# VBA: Can a set of "constants" be configured at runtime?

Tags: excel, vba, constants

When writing macros for processing spreadsheets, I like to set constants at the top of the module, corrosponding to the various column numbers I'll have to use. I recently had a case where I would need to perform the exact same task on two slightly different file layouts. My solution was to turn the constants into variables, and call a configuration sub to set them depending on the file to be processed. The only thing I don't like about that solution is that what was constant, and protected against careless user (or developer(!)) tweaks to the code, is now in a variable.

**Is there any way to make these configured values unchangeable in the main sub?**

**Original style:**

```
Const iColUser = 1
Const iColColor = 2
Const iColPet = 3

Sub Main()
iColUser = 3 '<--This line will prevent sub from running.
```

**New style:**

```
Dim iColUser As Integer
Dim iColColor As Integer
Dim iColPet As Integer

Sub Config()
Select Case SpreadsheetType
    Case a
        iColUser = 1
        iColColor = 2
        iColPet = 3
    Case b
        iColUser = 3
        iColColor = 2
        iColPet = 1
End Select
End Sub
Sub Main()
iColUser = 2 '<--This line will run, and cause major damage.
```

Comment: do you have rules governing possible-not harmful values of your "constant" variables? you could put them in a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Encapsulate* them**.

Add a class module, and make an *abstraction* over these. *Abstract away* the column numbering logic, *exose* `Property Get` accessors for your columns, and then another property with `Get` and `Let` accessors for the "mode", which determines the value returned by the properties.

```
Public Enum SpreadsheetType
    A
    B
End Enum

Private columnMode As SpreadsheetType

Public Property Get Mode() As SpreadsheetType
    Mode = columnMode
End Property

Public Property Let Mode(ByVal value As SpreadsheetType)
    columnMode = value
End Property

Public Property Get UserColumn() As Long
    Select Case Mode
        Case A
            UserColumn = 1
        Case B
            UserColumn = 3
    End Select
End Property

Public Property Get ColorColumn() As Long
    Select Case Mode
        Case A
            ColorColumn = 2
        Case B
            ColorColumn = 2
    End Select
End Property

Public Property Get PetColumn() As Long
    Select Case Mode
        Case A
            PetColumn = 3
        Case B
            PetColumn = 1
    End Select
End Property
```

Now to use it, you need an *instance* of the class. Assuming you called it `Class1` (gosh don't do that!), using it would look like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sheetColumns As New Class1

    sheetColumns.Mode = A
    Debug.Print sheetColumns.UserColumn 'outputs 1

    sheetColumns.Mode = B
    Debug.Print sheetColumns.UserColumn 'outputs 3

End Sub
```

The code using this object can only ever *read* the values, not *write* to them - unless you implemented a `Property Let` accessor for the mutable values.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like just what I'm looking for. I have only flirted with classes in VBA in the past. Sounds like it's time to get serious. :-)